# Combination of functions and coordinate geometry points

Tags: functions, coordinate-systems, combinatorial-geometry

Consider the functions $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and $g(x) = 7x + b$ in the standard $(x,y)$ coordinate plane, $y =f(g(x))$ passes through $(4,6)$. What is the value of b?

This question is forced me. Thanks for your helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=f(g(x))=\sqrt{g(x)}=\sqrt{7x+b}$$

Now plug in $x=4,y=6$
$$6=\sqrt{7 \times4 + b}$$

Comment: I didnt understand

Comment: Hey, which step do you have doubt? The first step or the plug-in step? (I've edited for both)

Comment: Oh this really helpful. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: @Bobtrollsten You're welcome!

Comment: But how you got $$y=f(g(x))=\sqrt{g(x)}=\sqrt{7x+b}$$ this?

Comment: So $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, which means for whatever number $a$, $f(a)$ maps it into $\sqrt{a}$ - And now notice that we set $a=g(x)$, because $g(x)$ is ultimately a number given a value of $x$

Comment: Oh I still could not understand that step

Comment: No worries. Let's try a simple example. What is $f(g(0))$? You first calculate $g(0)=b$, and then you calculate $f(g(0))=f(b)=\sqrt{b}$. Now could you try to extend to any value other than just $x=0$?

Comment: Thanks, got it now :)